# Accessing UITextField textfield from Objective-C++

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c++

I want to read a textfield value from Objective-C++ (.mm) after entering a new value in UITextField (.swift).

I can print "nsNumberVar" (new value) from swift and read "54321" (initialised value) from .mm but unable to read a new inserted value from .mm file.

What is the best and easiest way to solve this?

```
//.swift

@objc class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
{    
  @objc var nsNumberVar: Double = 54321

  @objc func textField3(textField:UITextField){
    textField3 = textField
    textField3?.placeholder = "some value"
}

@objc func okHandler(alert:UIAlertAction!){
    textView.text = "SOME VALUE: \(String(describing: 
    textField3!.text!))"

    guard let textField3 = textField3?.text
    else {
        return
    }
    let doubleValue = Double((textField3 as NSString).doubleValue)

    nsNumberVar = doubleValue
    //print(nsNumberVar)
}

func captured(image: UIImage) {
            imageOutlet.image = TestWrapper.originalImage(image)
        }

//.mm

@implementation TestWrapper
 +(UIImage *) originalImage:(UIImage *)image{
Mat inputImage;
UIImageToMat(image, inputImage);

    ViewController *a = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    std::cout << a.nsNumberVar<< endl;

return MatToUIImage(inputImage);
}
@end


//result -> unable to read a new value

54321
54321
54321
.
.
.
```

Comment: When is the Objective-C++ code executed?

Comment: I didn't include the whole Objective-C++ code but swift and Objective-C++ are executed simultaneously.

Comment: How does that happen? Who triggers the execution of both Swift and Objective-C++ at the same time?

Comment: Sorry maybe I am wrong. What I mean by working simultaneously is when I open this app (mainly camera), it shows the camera view (swift) and few functions from Objective-C++(.mm)

Comment: It's still not clear at which points in time the two sets of code execute. Please update the question with this (important) detail.

Comment: @Cristik Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it. I have updated the code. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: ViewController *a = [[ViewController alloc] init]; You are creating a new ViewController every time. So it only gives youth  initial value of nsNumberVar.

Comment: @E.Coms If that is the case, how can I rewrite this?

Comment: There is a lot to learn in this topic.

Comment: @E.Coms Thanks for your help.
do you think it would work if i create another viewController and insert a new value there and pass it onto existing viewController and its     "objc var nsNumberVar: Double" ?

Comment: I have no idea. You are not suppose to create a viewController by yourself in this case, just use an existing viewController from your app.